# How to handle this titanium webservice error?

Tags: web-services, soap, crash, titanium, appcelerator

I'm facing a error in the titanium whenever calling a SOAP webservice.

```
[ERROR] Error Domain=com.google.GDataXML Code=-1 "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.google.GDataXML error -1.)". in -[TiDOMDocumentProxy parseString:] (TiDOMDocumentProxy.m:50)
[ERROR] The application has crashed with an unhandled exception. Stack trace:
```

The application gets crashed right after this.

I've already placed try and catch blocks but no use.

please tell me why this happens and how to handle it.

thank you in advance.